# Link CMake built libraries to prebuilt object file

Tags: c++, build, cmake, linker

I have the following setup with one prebuilt object file (`payload.o`) and 4 libraries `lib1`,`lib2`,`lib3` and `lib4` all built by this `cmake` project.

```
prebuilt/
--- payload.o
lib1/
--- CMakeLists.txt
--- src/
--- ...
lib2/
--- CMakeLists.txt
--- src/
lib34/
--- Makefile
--- src1/
--- src2/
```

`payload.o` is a prebuilt object that is supplied and can't be build inside this `cmake` project.

`lib1` and `lib2` are `cmake` aware libraries and `lib3` and `lib4` are generated via a `Makefile` (`add_custom_command()`).

`lib2` depends on `lib1` symbols, `lib3` depends on `lib2` and `lib1` depends on `lib3`, furthermore `lib4` depends on `lib3`. As you can see it's a cyclic dependency graph.

Furthermore `payload.o` depends on both `lib3` and `lib4`.

---

The linker invocation i'm trying to achieve therefore is:

`ld prebuilt/payload.o -L <cmake build directory here> --start-group lib1 lib2 lib3 --end-group lib4`

I've tried adding the prebuilt object file via:

```
add_executable(payload IMPORTED prebuilt/payload.o)
target_link_libraries(payload lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4)
```

but this fails with the error message

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "payload" which is not built by this project
```

any ideas?

---

**abbreviated cmake file in question:**

```
project(...)
# build lib1/lib2
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)


# add custom command & target
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
    "${LIB3} ${LIB4}"
    COMMAND
...
    VERBATIM
    )
add_custom_target(lib34 DEPENDS "${LIB3} ${LIB4}")
add_dependencies(lib34 lib2)

add_library(lib3 STATIC IMPORTED ${LIB3})
add_dependencies(lib3 lib34)
add_library(lib4 STATIC IMPORTED ${LIB4})
add_dependencies(lib4 lib34)

# lib1 -> lib3
add_dependencies(lib1 lib3)

# payload target
add_executable(payload IMPORTED 
    prebuilt/payload.o
    )

add_dependencies(payload lib3 lib4)
target_link_libraries(payload lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 <...>)
```

Comment: Can we compile that `.o` into a static library with cmake, and then link against that static library? `add_executable IMPORTED` is for adding preexisting executables, but you could try `add_library( OBJECT IMPORTED)`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove imported:

```
add_executable(payload prebuilt/payload.o)
```

cmake should know what to do. `IMPORTED` is for executable build outside of cmake.

Alternatively you can specify imported object library, as that's exactly what you have - an object file builted by an external entity:

```
# import .o file as object library
add_library(payload_object OBJECT IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(payload_object IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/prebuilt/payload.o

# create payload executable, add payload objects
add_executable(payload ${TARGET_OBJECTS:payload_object})
```